# How to add pause and resume functionality for big processing spring boot API?

Tags: spring-boot

I have implemented one spring boot API which is used to do some third-party processing. Basically, this API is for processing of file after upload. So it may take time to process big files. So I want to implement pause and resume functionality for particular API. I have already implemented a method to resume file processing. But I am not able to stop running API. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you have already implemented.

Comment: Actually, what I implemented is not related to pause and resume spring boot API. Method process only that file records which are not processed before nothing else in the method.

Comment: Can anyone please help here.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added pause and resume functionality in spring boot API.

Comment: @RamanJoshi This is a place to share your code (questions&solutions), so if the next one that come with the same question doesn't have to ask a again. PLEASE SHARE YOUR SOLUTION!

Comment: I have achieved this by simple generic solution i.e. added variables IsPause, IsStopped in thread class and update it through some other API's for pause and stopped.